# facebook business manager, create system user

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

This may be a bit of a newbie question, but I'm struggling to create an admin system user (and system user) for my Facebook business manager through the graph-API.

Following this guide:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/businessmanager/systemuser/v2.3#systemuser

Posting something like this:

```
  curl \
 -F "name=Ad Server" \
 -F "role=SYSTEM_USER" \
 -F "access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>" \
 "https://graph.facebook.com/<API_VERSION>/<BUSINESS_ID>/system_users"
```

I'm getting this error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#3) Business Manager must be on whitelist", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 3
  }
}
```

I'm doing this on a newly created business manager, which is linked to a (public) Facebook app (whitelisted) and it also has a public page. The company I'm doing this for has a lot of activity on their business account, so I'm using this as a safe test environment. I cant find any information on how to get the business manager itself whitelisted.

The access token belongs to a admin user on that business account. I've tried other operations (like fetching all users) on the business account with this token and that works fine.

The reason why I'm doing this in the first place, is that I need an API user for an automated campaign-setup to manage adsets, custom audiences, adsets and ads. That user should not be directly linked with any personal facebook account. Creating a dummyaccount for this seems like a bad and possibly insecure solution.

Any help/suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Does your app have [Standard access to the Ads API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/access) and is your app claimed by your Business Manager?

Comment: Thanks this may be helpfull. App is claimed by business manager, I can make other calls with the access token to the business manager api. But the adsapi-access is missing from the app. I just applied for it now, since this is just a proxy app to be able to create a system user so a lot of the info required in the submission process (like screenshots) didnt really apply. Hope it passes anyway.

Comment: Did you solve this in the end?

Answer (score 5):

I have run into the same issue seconds ago. I have tried Graph-API AND Business manager (which seems to be much more comfortable).

Just have a look at: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/businessmanager/faq

> Q: What access token is used to create the system user? A: Create the
>   system user and fetch its token using the business manager UI at
>   business.facebook.com, under settings→system user. **you'll only see the
>   system user panel if your BM owns and app that has ads-api access, or
>   your owns an app that is specially whitelisted by your FB rep**.

This means:

1. Create the app you want to use in the first place
2. Add this app to your business (also somewhere within the business manager)
3. Add your admin-users ip at `https://developers.facebook.com/apps/<yourappid>/settings/advanced/`
4. Try system user creation again

It has worked in my case.

Comment: I didn't need to do step 3, but this was very helpful. Thanks!